# Can't load node.js module in main.js file of electron.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron

I've been building electron app and main.js file became to big so I desided to split it into modules. But some modules don't load and stop following modules from loading. I need to find out the source of this problem.
To load modules I use the following system:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...options
  });

  requireModules();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Load modules after mainWindow created
const requireModules = () => {
  require('./modulesMain/open')(mainWindow);
  require('./modulesMain/watchers')(mainWindow);

  require('./modulesMain/testModule')(mainWindow);
};
```

Modules after `require('./modulesMain/watchers')(mainWindow);` don't load. Module `watchers'` code:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { ipcMain } = electron;
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

const { transfPathForWin } = require('./helpersMain/helpers');

let watchedArray = [];

module.exports = (mainWindow) => {
  ipcMain.on('start-watching-dir', (event, dirPath, tabId) => {
    const perviouslyThisTab = watchedArray.find((item) => item.id === tabId);

    if (perviouslyThisTab) {
      perviouslyThisTab.watcher.close();
    }

    watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => item.id !== tabId);
    try {
        const winDirPath = transfPathForWin(dirPath);

        const watcher = chokidar.watch(winDirPath, {
          persistent: true,
          ignored: '*.sys',
          ignoreInitial: true,
          followSymlinks: true,
          cwd: '.',
          disableGlobbing: false,
          usePolling: false,
          interval: 100,
          binaryInterval: 300,
          alwaysStat: false,
          depth: 0,
          awaitWriteFinish: {
            stabilityThreshold: 2000,
            pollInterval: 100,
          },
          ignorePermissionErrors: false,
          atomic: true,
        });

        // Add event listeners.
        watcher
          .on('add', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been added`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('change', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('unlink', (path) => {
            console.log(`File ${path} has been removed`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
          .on('ready', () =>
            console.log('Initial scan complete. Ready for changes')
          )
          .on('addDir', (path) => {
            if (path === '..\\..\\..') return;
            console.log(`Directory ${path} has been added`);
            mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
          })
         .on('unlinkDir', (path) => {
           if (path === '..\\..\\..') return;
           console.log(`Directory ${path} has been removed`);
           mainWindow.webContents.send('refresh-tab', { tabId, dirPath });
         });

        watchedArray.push({ id: tabId, path: dirPath, watcher });
    } catch (err) {
      // error watching - no access or something
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on('stop-watching-dir', (event, dirPath, tabId) => {
    const watchedItem = watchedArray.find((item) => item.id === tabId);

    try {
      watchedItem.watcher.close();

      watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => item.id !== tabId);
    } catch (err) {
      // error watching - no access or something
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on('stop-watching-all', (event) => {
    watchedArray.map((item) => item.watcher.close());
    watchedArray = [];
  });

  ipcMain.on('close-tabs', (event, data) => {
    const { excludedTabs } = data;
    watchedArray = watchedArray.filter((item) => {
      if (excludedTabs.includes(item.id)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        item.watcher.close();
        return false;
      }
    });

    console.log('watchedArray', watchedArray);
  });
};
```

Comment: Not sure if that's a copy-paste error or not: you're missing the first character in the first line of watchers: `onst electron = require('electron');`

Comment: Yes, it's a copy-paste error

Comment: If I were you I would try to do elimination by commenting out ALL the events in watchers, then if all works well, start bringing them back one by one to see if there's a specific event handling that causes the freeze/crash. If it doesn't work with zero events it also help narrowing down the options (the wrapping code is the suspect) and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: it was incorrect import `const { transfPathForWin } = require('./helpersMain/helpers');` instead should be `const { transfPathForWin } = require('../helpersMain/helpers');` which caused path convertion error, which caused app crash. In addition I forgot to add `console.log(err)` in `catch` instruction, so `chokidar` crashed silently. The reason for following modules not to load was that module exported using function `module.exports = (mainWindow) => {...code}`, which crushed and that stopped `requireModules` function from continuing its execution and loading following modules